# Class not found even though it should be on the classpath

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I get this error when I shutdown my war running on Tomcat:

```
[2012-05-03 11:55:36,082] ERROR - org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(501) | Destroy method on bean with name 'threadPoolTaskExecutor' threw an exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    ... 8 more
```

In my pom.xml, I have spring-orm 3.1.1.RELEASE as a dependency. What's even more strange is that I can get into the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class which is a spring-orm 3.1.1.RELEASE class, yet it can't find the EntityManagerFactoryUtils class which is in the same jar. I'm guessing it must have something to do with it being abstract or static but I'm unsure in what further direction to investigate this issue. It really seems like it should be available.

Anyone have thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe you have a corrupt jar? Try cleaning and downloading the deps again.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler I freshly downloaded my jars and this didn't change anything. It's a bit baffling to me. This also occurs whether running in eclipse or on the command line with Tomcat.

Comment: Do you have different versions of the jar? Maybe in your war classpath and tomcat lib for example?

Comment: I just tried to add this version of `spring-orm` as dependency and was able to navigate to `EntityManagerFactoryUtils` in Idea without any issues. I assume you have no `scope` defined for this dependency, right?

Comment: @bluesman It is managed to 3.1.1. Moreover, the class has existed since at least 2.5.6. T

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov I have tried compile and runtime scope for this dependency. I too can navigate to it in my IDE. This is so weird :(

Comment: Did an older Spring jar get pulled in as a transitive dependency by chance?  you might need to add an exclusion.

Comment: @user944849 I looked at the dependency hierarchy for all my Spring jars and they're all 3.1.1. Again, the class that calls this is from the same jar that the missing class is from. I think it's even the same package. So it seems absurd to me that it can't find it :/

Comment: Check the dependency hierarchy for your whole app.  I've run across weird errors like this when including some jar that pulls in spring.jar:2.0.8 as a transitive dependency, when the rest of my app was using a later version.  Because the artifact IDs changed (Spring split the large spring.jar into smaller spring-core, spring-beans, etc.) Maven pulls both into your app.  The fix was to find the dependency including the old Spring jar & add an exclusion.  Spent hours on this the 1st time I encountered it.

Comment: Regarding @JeremyHeiler's comment, did you remove the jars from both your local artifact repo and any in-house remote repo you use (Nexus, Artifactory, etc.), getting fresh copies from Maven Central?  We've seen weird issues like yours when our Nexus instance gets hosed.  Or sometimes reindexing your remote repo does the trick.

Comment: @user944849 I only removed them from my local repo. It might take some effort to reindex the remote repo so I'll just download it from mavent central and try. I am pretty confident that there is no other spring jar that could conflict. I don't see it in the dependency hierarchy, in any of the deployed stuff, and type search also doesn't find any other version but 3.1.1. I'll look again though.

Comment: @user944849 After an unrelated architectural rework, this ended up disappearing. Don't know why it was happening but glad to see it was going. Must have been some kind of class loader issue, likely because Spring was half-assedly used (inherited an open source project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it might me an exclusion issue (try to call mvn dependency:tree to sort this out).

Do you have the jar in your war ? Do you have another Spring jar in Tomcat libs ? This could be a classloader issue.

Comment: I will investigate the tree shortly. I do have the jar in my war. There is not another version of this war in the tomcat libs.

Comment: I will accept this. I resolved my problem due to the result of some rework that was not intended to be related to this issue, but it solved it anyway. I imagine it was some kind of classloader issue. Before there was some weird hybrid mix of Spring and non Spring stuff and we moved it all to Spring and now that problem is gone.

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue ? how did you solve the issue by moving spring and non-spring issue ? Can you please state in detail what you did to get rid of this issue ?

Comment: How is this a solution? It offers no fix for the problem whatsoever other than "look at this, maybe it's this"...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by removing redundant dependency in one of my maven modules.
I had direct dependency and indirect through some other module and that caused this behavior.